# Reading from Sybase table with non-null BigInt gets JZ006: JZ0TC error

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

The error is "JZ006: Caught IOException: java.io.IOException: JZ0TC: Attempted conversion between an illegal pair of types"

I'm using JDBC via jconn3.jar to connect to the DB.  I can read just fine from a table that has a BigInt field that **can** be null, even when the BigInt field isn't null.  I can read every field **but** the BigInt field from the problematic tables.

Any idea why this is happening, and how to work around it?  Is this a known Sybase issue?

Comment: You should post the code used.

Comment: The "code" is "SELECT * FROM Table".  And with all due respect, if you couldn't figure that out from the post, you're highly unlikely to be able to offer me any suggestions.

Comment: Sure.. Keep up with the good attitude

Comment: You too! :-) And you might want to start with the assumption I'm not an idiot.  If there was anything special in the select, I would have included it

Comment: This is tagged java, I was asking for java code.. And if you sense "I think you are an idiot" in "You should post the code used" you should probably read again the help/faq section

Comment: It's tagged "Java" because I'm using jdbc to get to the server. And, it turns out that was the problem: the Sybase jdbc driver was the problem, and you're better off using jtds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with jconn3.jar.  Switching to jtds.jar (version 1.2.5) fixed the problem.